# Cancelling a unix process started by matlab

Tags: bash, matlab, unix, pid

Hi I'm trying to run a process xfoil in this case from matlab. The problem is sometimes xfoil crashes so to carry on without issue I need to run it as a background process. However now I end up with a race condition where xfoil hasn't finished by the time the data is needed. To solve this I added a pause statement, but in many cases the pause is too long. What I would like to do is record the process id when starting then within a while loop check if the process still exists.
For windows this is accomplished like so.

```
elseif(ispc)
    run_xfoil_command='start /b xfoil.exe < foilcommands > dump.out';
    [~,~] = system(run_xfoil_command);
    tic;
    % While xfoil hasn't finished running
    while (system('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq xfoil.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "xfoil.exe">NUL')==0)
        if (toc>5)
            [~,~] = system('taskkill /F /IM xfoil.exe > dump1.out');
            break
        end
        pause(0.2);
    end
    [~,~] = system('taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe > dump1.out');
end
```

However I can't figure out how to accomplish this in linux.
I've tried;

```
if(isunix)
    run_xfoil_command='pidof xfoil < foilcommands > dump.out &';
    setenv('GFORTRAN_STDIN_UNIT', '5')
    setenv('GFORTRAN_STDOUT_UNIT', '6')
    setenv('GFORTRAN_STDERR_UNIT', '0')
    tic;
    [stat,pid] = unix(run_xfoil_command)
```

However the process id is not returned in either pid, or the dump.out. Can anyone help to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: What about stat? Anything there?

Comment: According to the `man`,  `pidof` returns the `pid` of a _running_ program. How do you start your program?

Comment: By the way - if xfoil hasn't finished by the time you need the data, what is the desired outcome? Either you wait, or you didn't really need the data?

Comment: Run again with slightly different inputs. The main cause of failure is excessive separation preventing convergence so can be solved by reducing angle of attack, increasing Reynolds number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, `pidof` only gets the `pid` of a running program. If the command `xfoil` is what gets your program running, you should try

```
xfoil < foilcommands &; /sbin/pidof xfoil > dump.out
```

Then check the contents of `dump.out`. I think your `pid` will be there...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you are making just one mistake here.
the line

```
run_xfoil_command='pidof xfoil < foilcommands > dump.out &';
```

must be

```
run_xfoil_command='pidof xfoil > foilcommands > dump.out &';
```

pidof returns the process id of command xfoil which can be stored in foilcommands.